# How to get current position and show in map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to show a map with users current position , i am trying to get longitude and latitude on body load using HTML-5 and want to show map with get longitude and latitude. Here is my **index.html**

```js
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    //x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  /*x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
  */
  console.log(position.coords.latitude);
  console.log(position.coords.longitude);

}

function loadMap() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.719840899999998, 75.8824308),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("sample"), mapOptions);
  console.log(map);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD7lHDyDsOHYmd0tUrdbKKWpPlDkoDibik"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="getLocation()">
  <div id="sample" style="width:570px; height:580px;"></div>
  <button onclick="loadMap()">Show Map</button>
</body>

</html>
```

where i am doing wrong ? please help me .

Comment: And the problem is? `showPosition` isn't called? Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way is it right ? Have look of my updating code **index.js**

```js
function showPosition(position) {
    /*x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    */
    var vallat = position.coords.latitude;
    console.log(vallat);
    var vallong = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log(vallong);
    loadMap(vallat,vallong);
    // alert(position.coords.latitude);
    // alert(position.coords.longitude);
     
}
function loadMap(vallat,vallong) {
   
            var mapOptions = {
               //center:new google.maps.LatLng(22.719840899999998, 75.8824308), zoom:13,
               center:new google.maps.LatLng(vallat,vallong), zoom:13,
               mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
    
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("sample"),mapOptions);
            console.log(map);
         }
```

i am storing latitude  and longitude value in variable and passing in the loadmap. Its working but i want to show marker with my location. how to i can do it ?